# Java + Selenium: Unable to Locate Element by Attribute

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click a button on a page with the following HTML markup:

```
<html lang="en" webdriver="true">
<head>
<body class="scbody" style="background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAKCAYAAAB10jRKAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAADBJREFUeNpEyqERADAIBMGbbwSH+qhA/6URXMyqBUhFBLIP6ip0ezk2zExqC58nwACVZwX67tO41gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="), url("http://ir.ebaystatic.com/rs/v/res.img.pics.cmp.ds3.imgbg_jpg"); background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat; background-position: 0px 30px, 0px 0px;">
<div id="gh-gb" tabindex="-1"/>
<div class="scCont clearfix">
<div class="fl ml10 mr10">
<div id="globalheader" class="fl col_100p clearfix">
<div id="PageTitle" class="fl col_100p clearfix">
<div id="centralarea" class="fl col_100p clearfix">
<div id="rightSection" class="fr clearfix">
<div id="leftsection" class="fl clearfix">
<div id="CARTSection" class="fl dib col_100p">
<div id="ShopCart" class="fl col_100p">
<div class="c-std">
<p/>
<div id="sellerBucket_adoramacamera" class="fl col_100p">
<div id="sellerBucket_usacoinsupplies" class="fl col_100p">
<div id="sc_usacoinsupplies" class="fl cart_sci b-ddd bgclr-fcfcfc col_100p">
<div id="usacoinsupplies" class="sel_row sel_info_row" data-rtdisable="true" data-memberid="usacoinsupplies" data-count="2">
<div class="fl lalign ralign mw851px">
<div id="usacoinsupplies-itemGroup1" class="fl col_100p clearfix">
<div class="fl col_100p ">
<div id="usacoinsupplies-itemGroup1-item1" class="fl col_100p clearfix">
<div id="8460053414" class=" fl col_100p talign balign clearfix" data-varid="0" data-itemid="141494853656" data-hasmsg="false" data-displayorder="2" data-qty="1" data-iinfo="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*">
<div class="fr col_100p clearfix">
<div class="fr col_100p clearfix">
<div class="fr col_100p prltv">
<div class="tr">
<a class="action actionLink" aria-describedby="141494853656_title" aria-label="Remove" href="http://cart.payments.ebay.com/sc/rfc?iref=8460053414" data-irefid="8460053414">Remove</a>
<span class="mr10 ml10 linkClr">|</span>
<a class="action actionLink" aria-describedby="141494853656_title" aria-label="Save for later" href="http://cart.payments.ebay.com/sc/sfl?iref=8460053414" data-irefid="8460053414">Save for later</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ie7mb15"/>
```

The main part of the code is this:

```
 <a class="action actionLink" aria-describedby="141494853656_title" aria-label="Remove" href="http://cart.payments.ebay.com/sc/rfc?iref=8460053414" data-irefid="8460053414">Remove</a>
    <span class="mr10 ml10 linkClr">|</span>
    <a class="action actionLink" aria-describedby="141494853656_title" aria-label="Save for later" href="http://cart.payments.ebay.com/sc/sfl?iref=8460053414" data-irefid="8460053414">Save for later</a>
```

I thought of using the `aria-describeby` attribute to dynamically save an item for later as follows:

```
".//*[@aria-describedby=" + "'" + itemID + "_title']/div[2]/div/div/a[2]"
```

However, for some reason it never works. What am I doing wrong?

Note: There can be multiple items and the only way (I can think of) to identify a specific item is by the itemID - as other attributes are generated dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: The "main part of the code" that you showed has **no** `div` anywhere, yet in your XPath you are looking for `//div...`. How did you expect this to work?

Comment: I tried it with * too as seen in my XPath

Comment: You probably want **just** `"//a[@aria-describedby=" + "'" + itemID + "_title']`.

Comment: And take out the extra `" + "`: `"//a[@aria-describedby='" + itemID + "_title']"`

Comment: Did you try it? Bec I just tried `"//a[@aria-describedby='" + itemID + "_title']/div[2]/div/div/a[2]"` and it does not work.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think using xpath is bad practices , try to click using cssSelector :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".action")).click();
```

if you want to get element by attribute use something like this for example :

```
By.CssSelector("button[name='hasan']");
```